# How do I get the formula to either add 1 or stay the same?

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula

I have one cell that already has and adding formula. Now I want to say, if that answer is between 0&9, add 1. If the answer gets to 10, stop adding and leave it at 10. Basically, my employees accrue one PTO day per month, not to exceed 10 in a year. So I have, cell E11, E9+1. Now in the same cell, I was trying to tell it that when it adds that +1, if the answer comes out to be 0-10, that’s cool. But when the answer comes out to be more than 10, to just keep it at 10. I want the cell to stop adding +1 when the value gets to 10.

Comment: Welcome. You mention: *"I have one cell that already has and adding formula"*.  Still. One can see no formula. Do read [ask] and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. Also. Is this question about excel or google-sheets?

Comment: I’m using google sheets right now. Yes, the cell I’m working with (E11)is already adding a value of 1, from a different cell. So it say E9+1. Now I want that cell (E11, that says E9+1) to only add up to a value of 10. If E9+1 comes out to be 0-10 then that’s ok. Put that number in that cell. But if E9+1 come out to be more than 10, then only return a value if 10. I want E9+1 value to not exceed a value of 10

Comment: If I understand correct,try =MIN(10,E9+1)

Comment: @DanielleAdams Please read [ask] and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=MIN(10; E9+1)
```

or:

```
=IF(E9<10; E9+1; 10)
```